# how can I structprogramme?

Tags: bash

I would like to set up a master bash script that calls other sub bash  scritps

The script should be run as follows:
./scriptname.sh 10001

10001: is the argument defining the number of script to run (5 in total). if the argument is 1, the sub script is started and at 0, no action.

I created a table with sub scripts like:

`subscript1=source "${DOCROOT}/script1.sh"`
`subscript2=source "${DOCROOT}/script1.sh"
....`
`array=(${subscript1} ${subscript2} ${subscript3});`

The first problem is How I can with regex or other to match each bit as on argument (delete space between argument).
The second problem is I do not know how to associate my arguments (10001) to the table subs scripts.

a "*switch case*" is too long to implement and maintain in case of program evolution steps.

Can help me to structure the master script?

Comment: in the script to take all the arguments use $* and for and for argument counts $# and for every argument $1 $2 $3 ... and so on

Comment: you need include bash  ? `. script.name`

Comment: Please post the code you're currently using to actually invoke the sub-scripts; without it we're just guessing at what's wrong. At the moment it's not clear what arguments you want to pass.

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida `$*` is rarely what you want, with it your arguments will be split if there's whitespace in them. Use `"$@"` instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
   echo >&2 "$@"
   exit 1
}

arg="$1"

# Check that argument is valid (only 0's and 1's)
[[ $arg =~ ^[01]+$ ]] || die "Wrong argument \`$1'"

nargs=${#arg}

for ((i=1;i<=nargs;++i)); do
   valuei=${arg:i-1:1}
   # If value is 0, continue loop
   ((valuei)) || continue
   # Execute script
   echo "Executing subscript $i"
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./scriptname 10001
Executing script 1
Executing script 5
```

**Edit.** As you're asking how to execute the subscripts, here's a (fully working) possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Maximum number of subscripts
nsub=5

die() {
   echo >&2 "$@"
   exit 1
}

arg="$1"

# Check that we have argument of correct length
(( ${#arg}==nsub )) || die "Must give argument of length $nsub"

# Check that argument is valid (only 0's and 1's)
[[ $arg =~ ^[01]+$ ]] || die "Wrong argument \`$1'"

for ((i=1;i<=nsub;++i)); do
   # If value is 0, continue loop
   ((${arg:i-1:1})) || continue
   # Execute script
   source "${DOCROOT}/script$i.sh"
done
```

Comment: Thanks you for this reply. I still have not found the solution for how to handle in arguments. Any supositon ?

Comment: @ylas Edited to give you a possible possibility `;-)`

Comment: This solution can be worf only if the sub script's name are : script1.sh, script2.sh, script3.sh.... If the sub script name are : script_check.sh, script_tar.sh,script_crypt.sh, it can't work ?

Comment: @ylas, that's what you have in your question. If you have other requirements, please make them clear in your question.

Comment: But if you have them in an array, the arithmetic to get from 10001 to 1+16=17 to 2^0+2^4 to array[0]+array[4] is fairly straightforward. Doing it in pure shell is slightly painful but it should be a one-liner in `awk` or Perl.